# Is this input-output relation correct? Schmitt trigger

Tags: operational-amplifier, schmitt-trigger

[image]

OK, operational amplifier will want to keep node A at GND level. It will try to set its output so that the condition (inverting input potential = non-inverting input potential) is satisfied all the time.

So, why isn't a 5V of input mapping to -10 V which will hold node A at 0 V, but rather it is shown that +5V of input will result in +/- 12 V of output?

Comment: I think this slide is a very poor explanation of hysteresis. The equations given are linear equations, which implies that there is a linear relationship between the input and output voltages. But the circuit is highly non-linear so these equations are not useful and are confusing. Look for another source to explain the concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *OK, operational amplifier will want to keep node A at GND level. It
>   will try to set its output so that this(inverting input potential =
>   non-inverting input potential) happens all the time.*

It's not negative feedback - it's positive feedback. That's how a schmitt trigger works.

> *So, why isn't a 5V of input mapping to -10 V which will hold node A at
>   0 V*

It's not negative feedback. It's a non-inverting comparator with hysteresis.

Comment: so the shown graph will be valid after the opamp enters to saturation first time?

Comment: The graph looks good to me assuming the op-amp power rails are +/- 12 volt and that it's output can fully swing to the power rails.

Comment: Andy, I have been reviewing my questions, "It will try to set its output so that this(inverting input potential = non-inverting input potential) happens all the time." is this sentence of mine a valid statement only in case of when feedback from the input fed into the inverting input of an opAmp? I used to "memorized" this as a fact that an opAmp will always try yo keep its inputs at the same potential. However, now, reviewing your answer let me think that this is only special to negative feedback configurations. Can you confirm me?

Comment: Yes, that statement is only true with negative feedback. The comparator has positive feedback and it tries to maximize the voltage difference between the two op-amp (aka comparator) inputs @muyustan

Answer (score 1):

This circuit has positive feedback, so (in general) the inputs of the op-amp will not be equal.

The easiest way to analyze this circuit is to look at it at the instant of switching. They have given you Vout +/- so you don't have to worry about the op-amp output vs. the power supply rails.

With an ideal op-amp, the switching occurs when the inputs are at exactly the same voltage (in reality it may be a few mV for many op-amps).

In this case, the inverting input is grounded so we know the non-inverting input will (ideally) be exactly 0V when it switches. There are two cases- the output saturated at +12 or -12V.

For the non-inverting input to be 0V, the current through R1 is Vin/R1, so the output voltage must be 0V - (Vin/R1)R2 since there is no current flowing into the ideal op-amp inputs.

So +/-12 = -/+ (Vin * R2/R1) and thus Vin = -/+ (R1/R2)*(+/-12V)

So when Vout is +12 the ST will switch at -(R1/R2)*12 and when Vout is at -12, the ST will switch at Vin = +(R1/R2)* 12. In this case, -6V and +6V.

Just to make it perfectly clear, when the input is (say) at -12V the output will be at +12V. If you slowly increase then input voltage, the output stays at +12 until the input reaches +6V, at which point it rapidly switches to -12V. If you continue to increase the input, the output stays at -12V. If you then **decrease** the input, the output stays at -12V until the input reaches **-6V**, at which point it switches to +12V.

If the input is < -6V the output is always at +12V

If the input is > +6V the output is always at -12V

In between it could be *either* +12V or -12V depending on history of inputs.

---

You may also notice that if you make the ratio of R1/R2 too large, and the inputs are constrained to some power supply rails, there may not be enough voltage available at the input to make it switch, so it latches in one state or the other when the power is applied.

This kind of circuit is useful when the input signal is slow and/or has some noise on top of it so that the output can be made to switch only once on each edge of the input, instead of switching back and forth many times near Vin = 0V as a comparator without hysteresis would do.

Comment: IMO you have explained the dual *inverting comparator with hysteresis*.

Comment: hey, I started reading your answer, but, is it possible that you have mixed inverting and non-inverting inputs while you are typing? can you check?

Comment: @muyustan Yes, were reversed. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

As your opamp inputs near each other, within 10 microVolts, the output will start slewing (slowly) toward the opposite rail.

If you provided an overdrive (a step input that went from -10 microvolts to +100 microVolts, the output would slew 10X faster),

If you provided an overdrive that went from -10uV to +1,000 microVolts, the output would slew 100X faster.

Thus the speed of output changing is under your control.

On the other hand, if your input levels are +- 10 microVolts, which is near the level of internal random electron_movement in a 1MHz bandwidth assuming Rnoise inside the opamp is 10Kohms, your output behavior may be very unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some interesting (and not well known) considerations about this famous circuit solution:

1. The network of two resistors (R1 and R2) in series acts as a *passive voltage summing circuit with weighted inputs* (in the block diagram of a circuit with feedback, it is represented by a circle with two input and one output arrows). Most of the time it sums the constant voltage of the op-amp output (+12 or -12 V) with the varying input voltage. Only for the moment of transitions it sums two varying (in the same direction) voltages - the input and the output one.
2. If the input source has some internal resistance Ri, like in inverting circuits with negative feedback,  R1 may be omitted since its role will be played by Ri.
3. Although this is a circuit with positive feedback, here still there is a *virtual ground* that is inherent for inverting circuits with negative feedback. Only it appears here at the non-inverting input and only during the transition when the output voltage of the resistor summer crosses the zero voltage level.
4. Schmitt trigger is both analog and digital (discrete) circuit. It is analog only for the moment of transition; the rest of the time it is digital circuit.
5. This circuit behaves as a weird load with respect to the input source - when the input voltage is negative, it "sucks" current (through the R1-R2 resistor network) from the negative terminal of the input source; when the input voltage is positive, it "pushes" current (through the R2-R1 network) into the positive terminal of the input source. Thus it behaves like a *true negative resistor* (e.g., the so-called *current-inversion negative impedance converter* aka INIC).
6. If the input voltage is normally held inside the hysteresis loop (typically 0 V or in a high-impedance state... simply saying, *disconnected*), Schmitt trigger will become "Schmitt latch". It can be toggled by instantaneous change of the input voltage to positive or negative value above the high or low threshold. As you can see, there is no difference between the two circuits. The difference is only between the modes of operation: Schmitt trigger is forced by the input source to stay in one of its two possible states while Schmitt latch is left alone to store its last state. Hmmm... very interesting guess - besides an *electronic trigger*, the young Otto Schmitt invented also a 1-input *latch*?

But I wonder whether, after the grave silence of the "wise and capable" here,  I should continue to reveal more secrets of the famous circuit. Maybe there is no need of such a hard work... and it is better to find existing "definitions" and terms in reputable sources? Can erudition replace curiosity?

Comment: your answers are often quite different than ordinary, it sometimes helps me to understand essence of things, but unfortunately, sometimes, as in here, I really got lost in your answers. +1 and thanks for effort the anyways.

Comment: Right observations... Understanding is a difficult thing because it is based on past experience, not just on a simple accumulation of facts. To illustrate this, I will say you that I have reached these insights over a very long period of time... starting in the 80's...and until now. I recommend that you read the Wikipedia page dedicated to this circuit (much of it was written by me ten years ago and, thank God, has not yet been deleted). I have very good observations from your questions and comments. My remarks are a call for a more dignified behavior of other  people with pretensions...